# Replace varargs with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-functions

I'm using C++17 with templates and recursion to replace the C Va_Args.
Currently only floats are supported, more types are following once float is working ;)

```
class CWrite
{
public:
    template<typename NextT, typename ...RestT>
    static std::string Format(NextT next, RestT ... rest);

private:

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool is_float = std::is_same_v<T, float>;

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool IsValidParam();

    template<typename LastT>
    static std::string Format(LastT last);

    ///Empty param case
    static std::string Format();

};

// +++++++++++++++++++  Implementation ++++++++++++++++++++++++++

template<typename T>
constexpr bool CWrite::IsValidParam()
{
    bool bRes = false;
    bRes |= is_float<T>;
    return bRes;
}

template<typename NextT, typename ...RestT>
std::string CWrite::Format(NextT next, RestT ... rest)
{
    std::string strRes = Format(next);
    strRes += Format(rest...);
    return strRes;
}

template<typename LastT>
std::string CWrite::Format(LastT last)
{

    std::string strRes;
    if (is_float<LastT>)
    {
        strRes = "float:";
        char buffer[10] = { };
        snprintf(buffer, 10, "%f", last);
        strRes += buffer;
    }

    return strRes;
}

///Empty param case
std::string CWrite::Format()
{
    return "";
}
```

calling this with

```
std::string strRes = CWrite::Format(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5);
```

results in a warning for `snprintf()`
format '`%f`' expects argument of type '`double`', but argument 4 has type '`int`'

I'd expect that `IsValidParam` returns `false` for the last argument which should be an `int`.

https://onlinegdb.com/B1A72GHgU

Could you help me out here?
Did i miss something here?

Comment: How about `std::string CWrite::Format(float f)
{
    return "float:" + std::to_string(f);
}`?

Comment: hey thx that is a valid option as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C++17, you should use `if constexpr` in the following function

```
template<typename LastT>
std::string CWrite::Format(LastT last)
{

    std::string strRes;

    // VVVVVVVVV  <-- add "constexpr" here
    if constexpr (is_float<LastT>)
    {
        strRes = "float:";
        char buffer[10] = { };
        snprintf(buffer, 10, "%f", last);
        strRes += buffer;
    }

    return strRes;
}
```

The problem is that, using a simple `if` instead `if constexpr`, the compiler has to compile the statement (the part inside the `{ ... }`) also when `is_float<LastT>` is false.

If you can't use C++17... I suppose you can differentiate the function through overloading

```
std::string CWrite::Format (float last)
 {    
   std::string strRes { "float:" };

   char buffer[10] = { };
   snprintf(buffer, 10, "%f", last);

   return strRes += buffer;
 }

std::string CWrite::Format (int last)
 {    
   std::string strRes { "int:" };

   char buffer[10] = { };
   snprintf(buffer, 10, "%i", last);

   return strRes += buffer;
 }
```

Comment: thx that works nicely. However the eclipse has a problem with the if constexpr https://www.directupload.net/file/d/5693/vmhld2e4_png.htm. You wouldn't know how to fix that would you?

Comment: @Dr.Death - Sorry but... no idea. I suppose that your version of eclipse doesn't support C++17, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

max66's answer addresses the reason why your method has a problem with the format string and how to fix it. Basically you just need some way of picking a different format string based on the type of the value being formatted.

However, I'd like to point out another flaw: you assume that any given value will only require 9 characters to convert into a string. For very large values (e.g. `1e22`) this will fail. GCC will actually issue you a warning if it can determine this at compile time.

Additionally, your current implementation allocates many strings and recursively appends them together. This is - of course - highly inefficient and diminishes the speed of the `printf` family of functions to the point that it's not really worth using them.

Also your solution doesn't check for format errors (`snprintf()` returns negative in this case). And in such cases you may be appended undefined memory onto your string, as I'm not certain the C standard guarantees to null terminate the buffer on failure cases *(but it might)*.

My solution is to have a function that formats a given argument in-place onto the end of a `std::string`. Additionally it handles format errors and cases where 9 bytes is insufficient to hold the formatted value.

Additionally I impose SFINAE restrictions on the argument types to ensure it can only be called with types that we support.

Here's my solution with comments to explain what does what and why:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// checks if T is a type we support
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool allowed_type = std::is_floating_point_v<T> || std::is_integral_v<T>;

// the initial amount of space for stringifying each argument
constexpr std::size_t APPEND_PADDING = 20;

// returns the appropriate format string for type T (T assumed to be supported)
template<typename T>
const char *fmt_string()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>) return "%f";
    else return "%d";
}

// stringifys val onto the end of str (T assumed to be supported)
template<typename T>
void append(std::string &str, T val)
{
    std::size_t prev_size = str.size();     // remember the previous size of str
    str.resize(prev_size + APPEND_PADDING); // allocate the space we need
    const char *fmt = fmt_string<T>();      // get the format string to use

    // format the value and check the save the return value
    int res = snprintf(&str[prev_size], APPEND_PADDING, fmt, val);

    // on format error, just skip it (or )
    if (res < 0) str.resize(prev_size);

    // if we didn't have enough room we need to try again with the correct size
    if ((std::size_t)res >= APPEND_PADDING)
    {
        str.resize(prev_size + res + 1); // make space for the characters we need and the null terminator
        snprintf(&str[prev_size], res + 1, fmt, val); // format the string again (this time will work)
        str.pop_back(); // remove the null terminator
    }
    // otherwise we had enough room, so just truncate to the written characters
    else str.resize(prev_size + res);
}

// formats all of args into a single string (only allows supported types)
template<typename ...Args, std::enable_if_t<(allowed_type<Args> && ...), int> = 0>
std::string format(Args ...args)
{
    std::string str;                               // create an empty buffer string to store the result
    str.reserve(sizeof...(args) * APPEND_PADDING); // predict how much space we'll need for everything
    int _[] = { (append(str, args), 0)... };       // append all the args to str one at a time
    (void)_; // suppress unused variable warnings (will just be optimized away)
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << format(1, 2, 2.3, 3, 4.4, 5, 1e22) << '\n';
}
```

Note that this runs all the formatted strings together with no separation. Fixing this would be as simple as changing the format strings returned from `fmt_string()`.

I used different function names than you did, but you get the idea. `format()` is the function you would use.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I worked through your solution but I can not figure out 1 line. ```int _[] = { (append(str, args), 0)... };       // append all the args to str one at a time``` How can the return value of append be placed in an integer array. append() returns void?

Comment: @Dr.Death It's actually a comma expression: basically `(a, b)` evaluates to `b`, so it just constructs an array of zeroes. It's whole purpose is just to expand the pack and perform the appends in order